# how to avoid an app restarting on receiving an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent

Tags: android

My app asks the user for some input. Thereafter the user must present an NFC smartcard. Information is extracted from the card to be able to continue. The order of operations is important, both from a logical and practical stand-point. However when the NFC card is presented the activity is restarted (onCreate is called) and the user input gets destroyed. 
How can I prevent this to happen?

Comment: Are you declaring NDEF_DISCOVERED in an IntentFilter under the activity block in the manifest?

Comment: Yes. The NFC info can be read. ISO7816-4 commands can even be sent to the card. In my case I want to write to the card after the user has entered data.

Comment: that will cause the onCreate() method to be called every time you receive that Intent. You should declare a separate BroadcastReceiver component.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been reading about BroadcastReceiver, but the way it works together with an Activity is unclear to me. There are two scenarios possible:
1. The main activity is active, user enters data, then approaches the NFC tag.
2. The app is not active and BroadcastReceiver component gets activated on NDEF_DISCOVERED action.
Hence my questions:

Comment: Well it sounds like you only want to receive that action while the Activity is running, right?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been reading about BroadcastReceiver (I'm expert in smartcards, not android !!), but the way it works together with an Activity is unclear to me. There are two scenarios possible:
1. The main activity is active, user enters data, then approaches the NFC tag and intent is received by BroadcastReceiver component.
2. The app is not active and BroadcastReceiver component gets activated on NDEF_DISCOVERED action.
Hence my question: How can BroadcastReceiver differentiate between these two cases ?
Can you point me to any (non-trivial) sample code ?

Comment: So if the Activity is started, you want it to receive the data, and if it's not running, you then want to start the Activity, right?

Comment: To TheWanderer: Most of the time is an automatic action when the NFC tag is approached when card is already registered. When card is not registered, user must specify info, which will be written to the card when it is presented, hence this requires user input.

Comment: The activity is only needed when user must do input, otherwise BraodcastReceiver can launch asyncTask and finish off.

Comment: OK. You can do that pretty easily. Just check in the BroadcastReceiver (do a manifest-defined/static one) whether the card has the needed data (it's probably in the extras of the Intent), and if it does use that. If not, launch the Activity: `context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityClassThing.class)`

Comment: If the activity is already active, will context.startActivity nit destroy the user input?

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't need to start the Activity if the needed data is there. You can also use a static variable in the Activity class and set it to `true`/`false` in `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()` and then check that value from the BC.

Comment: I don't think so. The automatic action (when user has registered) does not require any visual user interface.

Comment: Can I access a variable in the activity when its onCreate wasn't called?

Comment: It needs to be static, but yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I now know how to go about it.(Sorry for my sometimes silly replies.)

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of receiving that action from within your Activity block in the manifest, make a dedicated BroadcastReceiver with that intent-filter in its manifest block.

In your Activity, you can define a public static variable:

```
public static boolean isRunning = false;
```

In your Activity's `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods, set that boolean appropriately.

You can also add the following field to your `<activity>` block in the manifest in stead of using the boolean:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

This will prevent a new version of the Activity from being created when `startActivity()` is called. I'm not completely sure that this will prevent onCreate() from being called, but it's cleaner than the boolean and worth trying.

If you use the boolean, just add a check in your BroadcastReceiver when you want to start the Activity:

```
if (!WhateverActivity.isRunning) {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, WhateverActivity.class));
}
```

If you want to just send some data from the BroadcastReceiver to your Activity, use a dynamic BroadcastReceiver in your Activity as well, with a custom Action and IntentFilter.

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Intent intent) {
        //handle the new data
    }
};
```